# Switch between two inner observables : switchMap doesn't unsubscribe previous subscription

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm building a screen with two [Ionic segments](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment) (one for each paginated entity type, let's say "poneys" and "aliens") and a list. For each of them, I must display an infinite list (not really), with an infinite scroll.

In my template, I'm subscribing to an observable called `entities$` like this :

**Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(entities$ | async) as entities">
      <ng-container *ngIf="entities.length > 0; else noResult">
        <ion-col>
          <ion-list>
            <entities-item
              *ngFor="let entity of entities; trackBy: trackByFn"
              [entity]="entity">
            </entities-item>
          </ion-list>
          <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadMoreData($event)">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content
              loadingSpinner="bubbles"
              [loadingText]="'common.actions.loadingMore' | translate">
            </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
          </ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-col>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

In my class, I'm building my observables like this :

**Class**

```
    const poneys$ = this.myService.entities$.pipe(
      map(entities => entities.filter(entity => entity.type === EntityType.PONEYS)),
      scan((acc, poneys) => [...acc, ...poneys]),
      tap(data => console.log('PONEYS')),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

    const aliens$ = this.myService.entities$.pipe(
      map(entities => entities.filter(entity => entity.type === EntityType.ALIENS)),
      scan((acc, aliens) => [...acc, ...aliens]),
      tap(data => console.log('ALIENS')),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

    this.entities$ = this.segment.ionChange.pipe(
      pluck('detail', 'value'),
      tap(segment => this.currentSegment = segment),
      startWith(this.currentSegment),
      switchMap(segment => segment === EntityType.PONEYS ? poneys$ : aliens$)
    );
```

**Additional details**

`entities$` is get from a `BehaviorSubject` (`asObservable` method).

I use `scan` operator to keep my entity collection previously fetched and concat with the new list emission.

I use `shareReplay(1)` to make sure that I'll get my latest emitted list after each switch between my two observables (I don't want to fetch again data already fetched).

**My Problem**
After switching between inner observables, if I scroll to get more data, the console shows "ALIENS" and "PONEYS", while it should display log of the current subscribed observable.
It Seems that previous subscription is never unsubsribe by switchMap.

Did I misunderstand something ?

Ty by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switchMap` does unsubscribe. You get this behaviour because of `shareReplay`. By default it won't unsubscribe from its source when there are no subscribers to the shared observable left.

If you want to get the latest accumulated values from `scan` here

```ts
const source = this.myService.entities$.pipe(
  map(entities => entities.filter(entity => entity.type === EntityType.X)),
  scan((acc, x) => [...acc, ...x])
)
```

then there has be a subscription running on this observable or you'll lose the accumulated values. You can use `shareReplay({ buffersize: 1, refCount: true })` to cancel the subscription to the inner source after a switch, but if you switch back, a new subscription has to be established to the `source` observable (i.e. the accumulated values from `scan` will be lost). So using `shareReplay({ buffersize: 1, refCount: true })` won't give you the desired effect in this scenario (i.e. the same as not using `shareReplay`).

As you want to keep the currently accumulated entities you need to keep a subscription to those open. Instead of switching back and forth between different entitiy streams you could just create one stream for accumulated entities of all types. Then combine this stream with the current segment and extract the accumulated entities for the given segment.

```ts
const accumulatedEntities$ = this.myService.entities$.pipe(
  scan((acc, entities) => groupBy(entities, "type", acc), {})
);

const segment$ = this.segment.ionChange.pipe(
  pluck('detail', 'value'),
  tap(segment => this.currentSegment = segment),
  startWith(this.currentSegment)
);

this.entities$ = combineLatest([accumulatedEntities$, segment$]).pipe(
  map(([entities, segment]) => entities[segment])
);

const groupBy = (data, key, initial) => {
  return data.reduce((storage, item) => {
    const group = item[key];
    storage[group] = storage[group] || [];
    storage[group].push(item);
    return storage;
  }, initial);
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xhje7b?file=index.ts

Comment: It works perfeclty, ty very much dude. I'm feeling bad 'cause what I did seems to be correct and perfeclty clear in my head :(.